# any document.body/getElementsByClassName/or any other return the same list with routes/layers, how is this possible?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var data = document.getElementsByClassName('searchauthor__input')[0].value;
```

in my js does not return any value. The above event listener works fine. It returns more code then fits in the console log (shown below in the code).

I have tried all different kinds of document.tags, all with the same response. Written a separate function for it.

```
     var searchA = document.getElementsByName('searchauthor')[0];
     searchA.addEventListener('click', searchAuthor);

     function searchAuthor(){
     var data = document.getElementsByClassName('searchauthor__input') 
     [0].value;
     console.log(data);
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
     }
     };
     xhttp.open("POST", "/database/searchdb", true);
     xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json;charset=UTF- 
     8");
     xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
     };
```

HTML:

```
          <div class="search">
          <p>Search by author</p>
          <input class="searchauthor__input" type="text">
          <button class="search__button" type="button" 
          name="searchauthor">Search</button>
          <p>Search by title</p>
          <input class="search__input">
          <button class="search__button" type="button" 
          name="searchtitle">Search</button>
          </div>
```

just a small piece of the `console.log(data)` response:

```
         route {
           path: '/database/searchdb',
           stack:
        [ Layer {
           handle: [Function],
           name: '<anonymous>',
           params: undefined,
           path: undefined,
           keys: [],
          regexp: { /^\/?$/i fast_star: false, fast_slash: false },
          method: 'post' } ],
          methods: { post: true } } }
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You are saying that the first line does not return any value, but then you are showing us the output of `console.log(data)`, so it seems `data` is indeed assigned value. So what's the problem now?

Comment: data = document.getElementsByClassName('searchauthor__input') 
     [0].value; is supposed to return a string value. Secondly, document.body will give exactly the same reponse in the console.

Comment: So it does return a value but not the value you want. Remove the line break after `document.getElementsByClassName('searchauthor__input')` from your code. `document.getElementsByClassName('searchauthor__input')[0].value` has to be in one line.

Comment: it is in one line. guess it got messed up in the editing for stack.

Comment: In that case, https://jsfiddle.net/0wq179Lf/ demonstrates that your code works. It logs the value entered in the text field. If that's different for you then your code must be different and your are not properly explaining what your issue is.

Comment: thanks alot for your help and putting in the time! Friend of mine figured out that the problem had to do with how I structured the data I send in the body and that indeed the value came out correct.

Comment: Glad you figured it out at least :)